# Процесс разработки на wordpress c git. Как правильно организовать?

Tags: wordpress

Разрабатываю сайт на worpress локально. Нужно процесс разработки показывать клиенту. Для этого есть хостинг на котором тоже установлен wordpress. Вопросы:

1. Что закидывать в гит, корневую папку wordpress или только wp-content?
2. Зачем мигрировать базу данных? Почему нельзя подключиться с локального сервера к базе на хостинге, чтобы была одна база для всех?

   Все туториалы, как правило подразумевают перенос сайта так сказать в конце разработки. Т.е. доделал, перенес на хостинг сдал клиенту и все. А как быть в случае правок уже запущенного в продакшн сайта? Например: сдал я сайт, через какое-то время звонит клиент, надо что-то добавить. Но за это время клиент в админке на хостинге добавил контент, пользователей. Мне придется копировать все с хостинга вместе с базой, доделывать и заливать обратно. А если за время пока я делал клиент на хостинге еще какой-то контент добавил. В таком случае при переносе базы с локалки его изменения пропадут. Как согласовать такой процесс?

Comment: 1. Что именно "разрабатываешь"? 2 "Локально" - это на винде? Тогда это детский сад и с геммороем. Сайт нужно разрабатывать в той среде, где он будет жить. 3. насчёт БД см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: @SeVlad к твоему сведению, главный коммиттер в ядро WordPress Сергей Бирюков работает локально на винде.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, Сергей коммитит не сайты, а движок. И, к твоему сведению (с), он так же не рекомендует заниматься разработкой сайтов  "на локалке".

Comment: @SeVlad а как же VVV, Docker, Local Lightning, Laragon? Ну и в конце концов - виртуалка. Сейчас в винде нативный линукс везде, ставится прямо из магазина

Comment: @mihdan Вируалка с линуксом в кач-ве локалки - меньшее из зол. А докер иже сними вообще из параллельной вселенной.

Comment: @SeVlad у меня нет слов, я пользуюсь этими инструментами много лет, видать вы не разработчик, раз для вас это так дико.

Comment: @mihdan не дико, а каждый инструмент для своих задач. А если ты много лет пользуешься экскаватором - это ещё не значит, что люди за рулём формулы1 не валяются водителями.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно, что разрабатываете локально - это избавляет от массы проблем при отладке кода, позволяет использовать локальные инструменты разработки - IDE с индексацией файлов и мгновенным поиском, отладчик, профайлер, код сниффер и т.д.

IDE - совершенно необходимый инструмент в наше время, позволяет проводить мгновенный поиск по всем файлам проекта, включая ядро WP (чтобы знать и проверить аргументы функции ядра). Если проект только на удалённом сервере, то IDE становится почти бесполезной.

Без отладчика xdebug проводить разработку сложных тем и плагинов попросту невозможно. Он позволяет делать остановки на произвольной строке кода, инспектировать там переменные, плюс предоставляет массу других возможностей, описание которых выходит далеко за рамки этого ответа. Чем сложнее ошибка, тем больше разрыв времени между поиском её в отладчике и распечаткой переменных. Бывали случаи, когда на поиск ошибки в отладчике уходили часы. Через распечатку переменных тот же самый процесс занял бы дни.

xdebug очень сильно тормозит php (3-6 раз, в зависимости от процессора). Использование xdebug на рабочем сервере невозможно. Даже при временном включении/отключении xdebug пользователи получат резкое снижение быстродействие сайта. В комментариях предлагалось размещать сайт разработки "рядом" с боевым, на том же сервере. Такой подход полностью исключает использование xdebug.

Если где-нибудь на собеседовании в современной команде разработки ядра, тем, плагинов, сайтов, вы предложите работать без xdebug, с вами просто не будут разговаривать.

Профайлер позволяет искать проблемные места в коде и улучшать быстродействие сайта, подчас радикально, в разы. Можно использовать профайлер от xdebug со всеми проблемами на удалённых серверах, описанными выше. Лучшее современное средство для профилирования - [Blackfire](https://blackfire.io). Система разработана специально для профилирования нагруженных рабочих серверов, но цены достаточно высокие. Бесплатный план работает только на локальном сервере.

Так что современная разработка тем и плагинов вне локального сервера попросту невозможна.

Теперь по ответам на вопросы.

1. В git следует закидывать только то, что вы разрабатываете - тему, плагины (на каждую сущность своя репа) - и не более того. Так вы предоставите самому себе возможность использовать код плагина многократно, на нескольких клиентских сайтах. Заливать в репу стандартные файлы WordPress вредно - что вы будете делать после обновления ядра?
2. Всё можно, но это неправильно. При разработке вы можете 20 раз испортить базу, откатить назад и т.д. При этом клиент не увидит текущих локальных проблем. Кроме того - а как вы собираетесь работать с одной и той же базой на разных доменах? Ведь домены наверняка разные локально и на хостинге? Не играетесь же вы с hosts. так что миграция базы необходима.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112762/discussion-on-answer-by-kagg-design----wordpress-c-git--).